# three.js: Error adding object to scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

Trying to add a simple object to a three.js scene. I'm getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cube is not defined`, but it seems to be defined to me. What am I doing wrong here?

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iXcEnsnHcVyemfZPIK1m?p=preview)

Here's the relevant js:

```
// Cube
   Cube = function(){  
            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );

                for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i += 2 ) {

                    var hex = Math.random() * 0xffffff;
                    geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHex( hex );
                    geometry.faces[ i + 1 ].color.setHex( hex );

                }

          var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, overdraw: 0.5 } );

    box = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            box.position.y = 25;

            }

        function createCube(){
          cube = new Cube();
    scene.add(cube);
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are wrong.

- You should be adding the cube mesh to the scene. So instead of `box = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );` put `return box = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );`
- call createCube() after you have defined the function

Comment: Thanks, you rock. Why is `return` needed? The code was working without it before I put it in a function, but now it does not work unless it's present.

Comment: not sure what you did before, but the WebGLRenderer does not know how to render a function. To render a object it needs a Mesh object. I guess if you wanted Cube () to be a class, you could make it accessible by putting `this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );` and then adding `cube.mesh` to the scene. Does that make sense?

Comment: To make it clearer, in the example you provided the cube mesh was in the private scope of the Cube object. The renderer can not access it if you declare it inside that function without returning it somehow

Comment: Thank you that's a super helpful explanation.